# How could I make iPhone 7 run iOS 16 in order to connect with an Apple Watch with watchOS 9?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, apple-watch, watchos

I would do anything if I could make my iPhone 7 (now on iOS 15.7) run iOS 16  in order to connect with an Apple Watch with watchOS 9. Would jailbreaking be a solution?

Comment: It is likely that the newer OS does not include drivers for the older phones' hardware; and that it also requires certain hardware that your phone lacks. 3-5 years is a good innings for a phone to be supported. It will of course still run on ios15, which should keep you compatible with most software for a couple of years.

Comment: @benwiggy I know, but I want to make my iphone7 to connect watchOS9 which only connect to iOs16 or newer.

Comment: @Victor If that is your actual question, please ask that! It is possible to use an Apple Watch on watchOS 9 with iOS 15, so if that’s all you need that’s your actual problem and should be your real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t run iOS 16 on an iPhone 7. However, you can use an Apple Watch with watchOS 9 on iOS 15 with [**Legizmo**](https://legizmo.app/).

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run iOS 16 on iPhone 7

You cannot connect a Watch running watchOS 9 to an iPhone running iOS 15.

Watches sold with watchOS 9 shipping indicate this in their system requirements, with the following text appearing directly above "Add to Bag":

> Apple Watch requires an iPhone 8 or later with iOS 16 or later.

Apple Support will uninstall beta versions of watchOS, but they will always install the latest compatible release version. They will not revert to a previous version. If the watch did not come with watchOS 9, but has been updated to watchOS 9 it can no longer be used without iOS 16 or later on your iPhone.